# How to brightly light an entire backyard area with only one electrical box?

Tags: electrical, lighting, light-fixture, security, bulb

The end goal is a security light for a backyard that provides ~10,000 lumens total output over an area of roughly 85 x 45 feet  (26 x 14 meters).

The problem is I haven’t found any ready made way to do that using a single fixture (to avoid adding another electrical box to the back of the house).

Could a standard two bulb fixture could come close using two powerful LED bulbs, or would a more DYI solution be requires to make it possible and practical?

What have I tried or thought of so far:

- I know there are bulbs bright enough for other uses. I just added a 60w LED corn bulb in the garage and wow, it makes working at night wonderful.  However corn bulbs don’t seem to be the right fit for a backyard floodlight, for example they’d be wasting light by shining 360 degrees.
- I’ve also seen standard A19 LED bulbs at 22 watts which is of course very bright, but wouldn’t do the job with only two sockets, and again seems it may not be optimal to light up a backyard even if you fit in the ~5 bulbs it would take.

Maybe something like this wall light would be required?
[https://www.amazon.com/Ustellar-Waterproof-Equivalent-Floodlight-Landscape/dp/B01NBTB717](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B01NBTB717)

Maybe there is no bulb solution which would mean forgetting standard two socket security light fixtures and I’m just looking for the best options.

Comment: off-road driving lights and a 12V power supply

Comment: You're tying your hands behind your back trying to use COTS "2 lamp + motion sensor" units.  Those require floodlamp types and very bright E26 floodlights aren't super common.  [Here's one](https://www.superbrightleds.com/moreinfo/par-led-bulbs/par30-led-bulb-40-watt-led-spotlight-bulb-flood-light-bulb/1700/).  The Amazon bulbs are Cheese junk with no proper listing from any reputable testing lab.

Comment: I'd use: socket-to-plug adapter, a cheap SSR heatsink, and a 50w driverless LED module, X2. I use one 20w module in my backyard, which puts 100 lux by the house and 5-10lux on the fringe, about 35' away.

Comment: @jsotola serious? never even thought of this. if there s blog article please post a link otherwise i’ll search it up. thx.

Comment: @harper Yes you’re right it’s tieing my hands, that’s why I want to stay open to the possibility it’s just not the best way to go.  As far as Chinese Amazon bulbs being junk, I’ve had some luck, gotta use fakespot.com to verify reviews.  For example my corn bulb has performed very well (https://www.amazon.com/gp/product/B0192ZGXSG), and also the LedMo stuff has been well performing and reliable (https://www.amazon.com/gp/product/B01N6QZ4WB). But I do realize you have to wade through tons of junk.

Comment: @dandavis that’s beyond my current understanding but thank you because now i can research to learn and figure it out as a possible option.

Comment: The [50w COB plates found online](https://www.ebay.com/sch/i.html?_from=R40&_nkw=cob+110v&_sacat=0&_sop=15&LH_BIN=1) are very bright, but get hot. [Solid State Relay heatsinks](https://www.ebay.com/sch/i.html?&_nkw=ssr+heatsink&_sacat=0&LH_TitleDesc=0&_sop=15&_osacat=0&_odkw=cob+110v&LH_BIN=1) are huge and cheap. You will need to do a little research to wire it up safely, but it's only two wires and patience in the end. After having bought hundreds of things LED (strips, bulbs, USB lamps, COBs, SMD chips, retrofits, etc), I don't know of a way to get more lumens from the small space of a lamp.

Comment: @dandavis you're really talking about scratch-building something from electronics-kit parts. That's not a thing we do *here* on the diy stack.  Electronics stack, absolutely.

Comment: @Harper: I'm suggesting to combine 2 or 3 off the shelf parts, not a scratch build, and besides, isn't this Do It Yourself? Screwing in a lightbulb is a joke punchline, not DIY. With 2 50w modules, and an hour of effort, OP would have 1000w tungsten equiv, far more than most turn-key options. Maybe a bridge too far, but an option.

Comment: @dandavis Oh, I've been tempted, as they "would" solve problems I can't solve otherwise.  However I am acutely aware of issues attaching heatsinks, coming up with proper enclosures, waterproofing, lensing (which is a HUGE aspect of OP's issue even though he's not minding it), safety, and generally making the thing last longer than a month outside.   You know they also sell those same emitters already enclosed with driver and heatsink and all those problems solved, and line cord attached.

Comment: OP  your main issue is aiming of the light.  All the lights you are looking at emit a 140-160 cone, which will light your lawn, the wall, your neighbor's bedroom and half the sky. LED's best characteristic is that they emit greatly less than a sphere, and lend themselves to aiming with efficient **lenses** instead of weak reflectors.  So figure out how to light what you want, and not what you don't.  You'll need way less lumens to get er done.

Comment: @ThreePhaseEel Edited question please remove it from hold or explain remaining objections.

Comment: Wth? The question was put on hold with a request for editing if possible, I edited title, structure, and content in an attempt to address concerns, and requested feedback or reopening, Then it’s closed without comment? @Tyson

Answer (score 1):

Short answer to your question no. I don't know why or how you came to need a 10,000 lumen LED but that would be the equivalent of a 250W High pressure gas type lamp. The E26 lamps are manufactured to replace an incandescent, edison base fixture. They do make retrofits for 10,000 lumen lamps but they would have a mogul base and be ballast driven.

The largest medium (edison) base incandescent manufactured is 500W which is about 6500 lumens so there would be no need to manufacture an LED retrofit any larger than that. Not saying someone might claim to have one but I would be highly sceptical.

Hope this helps.

Comment: I would certainly use a HID light if I wanted 360 degree light. However it doesn't work with a motion sensor.